# React loadable unable to load component on every new build unless refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-loadable

I've been facing this issue since a while, when ever I create new build in production I got load error unless I refresh the page. The service worker is getting updated fine but don't know whats going on.

I've been using the following packages

1. react-create-app
2. react-loadable
3. service worker coming along the
   create-react-app

I even add the service-worker.js in nginx ignore cache

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I'm importing the component

```
{
    path: '/products/create',
    name: 'Products Create',
    exact: true,
    auth: true,
    component: Loadable({
      loader: () => import('./pages/update'),
      loading: LoadingComponent,
    }),
  },
```

webpack is making the chunks properly and updating the service-worker.js on creating new build.

If I disable the service worker then it keeps serving the old code from cache until I clear that.

But when I enable the service-worker, It keep on loading my error component until I refresh the page.

Comment: Share your config and your code. No one can help you with this undetailed question.

Comment: I didn't ejected the project and using the default "create-react-app" configuration.

let me share the code